# How can I create a raw device on top of an LVM block?

Tags: mount, lvm

I have disks which are LVM devices. Is there a way that I can create a raw write-able disk on top of them?  By raw, I mean, a file which is seen as a true block device by the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

After you create your logical volume (consisting of a volume group with one or more physical volumes), the end result should be a block device in `/dev/mapper` that you can use as you would any block device.

Typically you'll `mke2fs` or similar it and then `mount` it, but you can do what you want with it.

I believe if you wanted you could even use that as a physical volume in a new volume group.

Comment: mkfs.xfs: warning: unable to probe device toplology for device /dev/mapper/
mkfs.xfs: cannot open /dev/mapper/: Is a directory

Comment: Do an `ls /dev/mapper` - one of the files in that directory would be the device file.

Comment: That also fails:  mkfs.xfs: /dev/mapper/vg_mrg11-lv_home contains a mounted filesystem (but nothing is mounted).

Comment: i believe if ANYTHING is mounted in /dev/mapper, you cannot format.

Comment: It has to be mounted somewhere.  Update your question with the output of `mount` as root.  Or try an `umount /dev/mapper/vg_mrg11-lv_home` - if that fails, try a `lsof -i | grep vg_mrg11-lv_home`